# Merge two dataframes with same dimensions (mxn) and column/index names into a new (3D) data frame where each column is divided into two subcolumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (A and B) with same column/index names. I want to merge them into a new dataframe where each column is divided into two subcolumns (A and B).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for MultiIndex in columns by parameter `keys`:

```
np.random.seed(2023)

A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))

df = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1, keys=('A','B'))
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   A        B
   a  b  c  a  b  c
0  7  9  6  5  0  6
1  7  1  3  1  5  7
2  4  4  6  5  8  2
```